# How we get Customerid of Stripein Swift

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I want to get Customerid of  Stripe  After Saving Card I got STPToken .I am unable create customerid from STPToken From Swift. Please Help. Here is my code snippet.

```
let paymentConfig = STPPaymentConfiguration.init();
        paymentConfig.requiredBillingAddressFields = STPBillingAddressFields.none;
        paymentConfig.publishableKey = "pk_test_whRD827lMXvFb1MtY9T7bRzW"
        let theme = STPTheme.default();
        let addCardViewController = STPAddCardViewController.init(configuration: paymentConfig, theme: theme);
        addCardViewController.delegate = self;
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: addCardViewController);
        self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil);


   func addCardViewController(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController, didCreateToken token: STPToken, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
        print(token)
        dismiss(animated: true)


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not get customer id from the client. It should be generated on your server. Here is the reference for your server to generate customer,

https://stripe.com/docs/api/dotnet#create_customer

You should have an API to send `stptoken` on your server and then your server should create a `customer` and return the `customerId` in the response.